# Oracle Sql adding hours and minute to a to_date while insert statment

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, sql-insert, date-arithmetic

Hello I am trying to make an insert statement which includes adding 2 hours and 10 minutes to a to_date .

But i do not know which function i can use.

this is my statement so far

```
insert into xyz values (TO_DATE('22-Oct-2020 11:00 AM', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI AM'))
```

but i want to add 2 hours and 10 minutes to the above while inserting.

Comment: what function would i need to use if i wanted to just add days only as well ?

Comment: Note, format `MM` actually means months number. Proper syntax would be `TO_DATE('22-Oct-2020 11:00 AM', 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH:MI AM', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American')`

Answer (score 2):

Use date arithmetics. In Oracle, you can add decimal values to a date (`1` stands for "1 day"):

```
insert into xyz 
values (
    to_date('22-Oct-2020 11:00 AM', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI AM') 
    + 2/24 + 10 / 60 / 24
)
```

Or:

```
insert into xyz 
values (
    to_date('22-Oct-2020 11:00 AM', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI AM') 
    + interval '2' hour + interval '10' minute
)
```

Or (with credits to Wernfried Domscheit):

```
insert into xyz 
values (
    to_date('22-Oct-2020 11:00 AM', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI AM') 
    + interval '2:10' hour to minute
)
```

Comment: You can also write `+ interval '2:10' hour to minute`

Comment: would this automatiicaly change the AM to a PM ?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: yes, indeed. I added that to my answer, for completeness. Thank you!

Comment: thank you so much i spent so much time trying addtime,dateadd() etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `interval` as well,

```
insert into xyz values (TO_DATE('22-Oct-2020 11:00 AM', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI AM') + interval '130' minute);
       
        
select TO_DATE('22-Oct-2020 11:00 AM', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI AM') + interval '130' minute from dual;
    
TO_DATE('22-OCT-202
-------------------
22-10-2020 01:10 PM
       

select TO_DATE('22-Oct-2020 11:00 AM', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI AM') + interval '1' day from dual;
    
TO_DATE('22-OCT-202
-------------------
23-10-2020 11:00 AM
```